# Sort values in list of dictionaries containing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that has a list as it's value. I want to sort this list of dictionaries based on the values of the list. This is what the data looks like:

```
[{'len': [[1.0, 0.15167129908211108],
   [0.15167129908211108, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'count': [[1.0, -0.0062137259524966066],
   [-0.006213725952496607, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'dom_length': [[0.9999999999999999, 0.14866302421674646],
   [0.14866302421674643, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'p_length': [[1.0, 0.06551622215539057],
   [0.06551622215539057, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'date_length': [[1.0, 0.18233544694774714],
   [0.18233544694774714, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'file_length': [[0.9999999999999998, 0.08244043289497642],
   [0.08244043289497642, 0.9999999999999999]]}]
```

I want to sort this data in order to return the top 3 dictionaries. This is the desired output :

```
[{'date_length': [[1.0, 0.18233544694774714],
  [0.18233544694774714, 0.9999999999999999]]},
  {'len': [[1.0, 0.15167129908211108],
   [0.15167129908211108, 0.9999999999999999]]},
  {'dom_length': [[0.9999999999999999, 0.14866302421674646],
   [0.14866302421674643, 0.9999999999999999]]}]
```

Comment: What makes a dictionary 'greater' than another, in your case?

Comment: The values in the list of lists other than 1 or 0.999. It is those ones I am trying to compare.

Comment: @user872009 Looks like the values will always be either identical or very similar, except for rounding errors I suppose – would it be enough to compare just one of the values? Or can they be (much) different, and if so, what would happen if one is larger and the other is smaller, which would take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the `sum` of the `sum`s of the sublists, then get the top `3` (assuming there's only one `key-value` pair in the dictionary, otherwise you'd need another outer `sum`, or another criteria):

```
>>> sorted(your_list, key=lambda obj: sum(sum(sl) for sl in list(obj.values())[0]), reverse=True)[:3]
[{'date_length': [[1.0, 0.18233544694774714], [0.18233544694774714, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'len': [[1.0, 0.15167129908211108], [0.15167129908211108, 0.9999999999999999]]},
 {'dom_length': [[0.9999999999999999, 0.14866302421674646], [0.14866302421674643, 0.9999999999999999]]}]
```